# Modelling location based tags in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, morphia

This is my scenario:

A user stores an activity in a selected location and adds a set of tags to it.
Now I would like to get a list of the most popular tags around that location as suggestions to the user upon creation. I'm unsure of how to model the tags in MongoDB and how to query for the the most popular tags close to a location.

This is what I got:

The activity is stored with the location and a list of selected tags (just the tag names for fast retrieval).

```
{
    name: <name of activity>,
    coords: [longitude,latitude],
    tags: [tag1, tag2, tag3]
}
```

When the activity is created we store the tag stats in a separate collection like this:

```
{
    name: <tag name>
    locations: [
        {
            coords: [longitude,latitude]
            count: <times added to this location>
        },
        {
            coords: [longitude2,latitude2]
            count: <times added to this location>
        }
    ]
}
```

Currently we're running MongoDB 2.4 with Morphia, but I guess upgrading to 2.6 would probably be advisable as there are some improvements with geospatial indexing. Maybe we also need to go to the native Java driver as it looks like Morphia isn't really there yet. All of these is possible as long as we find a good solution on our model/query.

Comment: I am not sure about the tag stats collection, since if I understood your problem you need to search all the time based on location and never based on tag name. So using the aggregation framework you could just `match` the documents that have tags in the area and then `unwind` and `count` the most popular tags.

Comment: Yes, see, $geoNear and aggregation framework. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/ There are some restrictions, such as that the geoNear needs to be the first stage -- which it would be in your case. If you need to search on some other characteristic and then spatially, look at haystack indexes. And, yes, I would say the improvements to spatial/aggregation would justify upgrading to 2.6.